# How put session in login php

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to ask how to put and write session in login.php? I want my application can know the current account login in my application. I would like to use session method to implement my login php. Because later after user login, user will key in their data and the data will send to database and the data entered by that user will display in that user account only. 
This is my Login.php

```
<?php 
require_once '../includes/DbOperations.php';
$response = array(); 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
if(isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
    $db = new DbOperations(); 

    if($db->userLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
        $user = $db->getUserByUsername($_POST['username']);
        $response['error'] = false; 
        $response['id'] = $user['id'];
        $response['email'] = $user['email'];
        $response['username'] = $user['username'];
    }else{
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = "Invalid username or password";          
    }

}else{
    $response['error'] = true; 
    $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
}
}
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

This is my DbOperations.php

```
<?php 

class DbOperations{

    private $con; 

    function __construct(){

        require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/DbConnect.php';

        $db = new DbConnect();

        $this->con = $db->connect();

    }

    /*CRUD -> C -> CREATE */

    public function createUser($username, $pass, $email){
        if($this->isUserExist($username,$email)){
            return 0; 
        }else{
            $password = md5($pass);
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?);");
            $stmt->bind_param("sss",$username,$password,$email);

            if($stmt->execute()){
                return 1; 
            }else{
                return 2; 
            }
        }
    }

    public function userLogin($username, $pass){
        $password = md5($pass);
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$username,$password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result(); 
        return $stmt->num_rows > 0; 
    }

    public function getUserByUsername($username){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
    }


    private function isUserExist($username, $email){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $email);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->store_result(); 
        return $stmt->num_rows > 0; 
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: `session_start();` and `$_SESSION['username'] = $user['username']` where you storing the `response`.

Answer (score 0):

To use sessions in PHP, you first need to start the session with [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php). You should do this on every page that you want to use the session.

```
session_start();
```

Once the session is started you can store variables in it, e.g.

```
if($db->userLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
    $user = $db->getUserByUsername($_POST['username']);
    $response['error'] = false; 
    $response['id'] = $user['id'];
    $response['email'] = $user['email'];
    $response['username'] = $user['username'];
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $user['id'];
}else{
    $response['error'] = true; 
    $response['message'] = "Invalid username or password";          
}
```

Once you are finished with the session and want to destroy it, e.g. when a user logs out, you should run [session_destroy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php).

Comment: after login, my application will go insert data interface, is the way of write session in insert data interface same as login.php? Because now i add one more column in data table with user_id which is foreign key. My login table user_id is primary key

Comment: Yes you always write and read from the session in the same way. Just make sure you have called `session_start()` or it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

- `session_start();` to start session,
- `$_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];` to set variable from session,
- `session_unset();` to free session variables,
- `session_destroy();` to delete session.